# PHP array curly brackets instead of square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, json, curly-braces

I'm attempting to output curly brackets from my array like this:

```
"data":{facebook":{"message"}},
```

but I keep getting square brackets:

```
"data":{"facebook":["message"]}
```

Here is my code:

```
$output["contextOut"] = array(array("name" => "$next-context", "parameters" =>
array("param1" => $param1value, "param2" => $param2value)));
$output["speech"] = $outputtext;
$output["data"] = array("facebook" => array("message"));
$output["displayText"] = $outputtext;
$output["source"] = "index.php";
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($output);
```

and this is my json encoded output:

```
{"contextOut":[{"name":"buy-context","parameters":{"param1":null,"param2":null}}],"speech":"msg","data":{"facebook":["message"]},"displayText":"msg","source":"index.php"}
```

How do I obtain the curly brackets instead of the square brackets? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `{}` is for __object__.

Comment: See [JSON Syntax](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Thanks, referenced the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Crovella said, your stated goal is invalid JSON.

Your valid options are for the `facebook` property to directly contain the message string:

```
{
    "data":{"facebook":"message"},
}
```

*(note I've added the outer `{` and `}` missing from your question)* ...in which case you want:

```
$output["data"] = array("facebook" => "message");
```

Or you can make `facebook` refer to an object with a `message` property that has a value, like this:

```
{
    "data":{"facebook":{"message":"value"}},
}
```

by doing this:

```
$output["data"] = array("facebook" => array("message" => "value"));
```